# Doublespacing for contents but not for the space between the header and the contents

Tags: formatting

I'm using `\onehalfspacing` for my entire document, except for the table of contents for which I use `\doublespacing`. However, the space between the heading "Contents" and the first line of it is also doublespaced, making it look different from the rest of the document.

What I want is `\doublespacing` only taking effect **after** the first line of the contents.

Comment: Hard to answer unless you show a MWE which shows how you are determining your headers. You will need to change the code for your headers (e.g you may be using the titlesec package)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing

\tableofcontents

\onehalfspacing

\chapter{First}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\doublespacing}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\section{Foo bar}

\chapter{Last}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\section{Foo bar}


\end{document}
```